# Why is this URL Request is not being called?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios6

I have the following code as part of an iOS app which takes a JSON array from a URL and uses it to populate a table view. For some reason, the request isn't being made in the function, and I can't figure out why. The function is shown below.

P.S - I'm a newbie to this Objective-C lark, so forgive me if I've made a really obvious mistake!

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    // Create a URL Request
    self.responseData = [NSMutableData data];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
    [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mydomain.com/return_json_list"]];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    self.viewController = [[BIDViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BIDViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: the request is asynchronous and will report back to your delegate methods. So you need to implement some of the `NSURLConnectionDelegate` methods for example: `– connection:didReceiveResponse:`. Check https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html for docs

Answer (score 0):

You never actually make the request... You need to call `start` (async) on the `NSURLConnection` or `+ (NSData *)sendSynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request returningResponse:(NSURLResponse **)response error:(NSError **)error` (synchronous).

You can accomplish the latter with:

```
self.responseData = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mydomain.com/return_json_list"]];
```

Be aware that it will occur on the main thread, so your UI will be affected.

Comment: It's a bad idea to clog up main thread with synchronous requests, especially as the json data to be downloaded could take some time. Also, you don't need to call `start` - calling `initWithRequest:delegate:` is the same as calling `initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately:YES`